# How to create a log file document which is not editable by a word processor on SD card

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, programming, sd-card

I'm using a **Arduino Mega 2560**  and **SD card shield** to make an industrial logging panel. Is there any way to write log data document in a **read-only type** file like a **pdf** on SD card so that the contents cannot be edited once created by word processing software? The data has to presented as a document on a windows machine.

Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point let me know in the comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71744/discussion-on-question-by-nithin-varghese-how-to-create-a-log-file-document-whic).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a file that cannot be edited.

If a file can be read it can be edited.

However, there are ways of making it possible to know if a file has been edited - i.e., to integrity check the file. To make it *hard* to edit a file and maintain the intrinsic integrity of the file.

The simplest method is to create a checksum of the data in the file and store that in the file as well. If the data is, for example, a CSV file, you could include in each row a checksum of the data in that row as an extra column. If the data gets changed the checksum will no longer match. Of course, that doesn't preclude someone calculating the new checksum and entering that.  So maybe adding a checksum of all the checksums at the end of the file as well so you know if any checksums have changed.

Again, it's possible for someone to recalculate that checksum as well.

The most secure method is to digitally sign the file (in the way the PGP or GnuPG does). Without the private key, it's impossible to re-sign the file after modification. However, that kind of operation is comparatively heavyweight and not something an Arduino is particularly suited to doing (I'm not sure if it's even physically possible given the lack of resources an Arduino has).